Bookworm Rpi3a+ running at 1.2GHz, cannot hit 1.4GHz
In previous version of RPI OSes it was easy to just put
arm_freq=1500
overvoltage=6
into config.txt and system would overclock itself....
However i tried now do same now with Pi3a+ and it always stays at 1200MHz max, no matter what i do.
Has something changed, that overclocking does not work anymore like before?
I am using bookworm lite 64bit, updated. CPU has a small heatsink on it.

Odd - My 3A+ runs up to the expected 1.4GHz - no overclock at all - what does /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq say?

it says 1400, however when i put system into stress test (stress -c 4 -t 60 &) and view vcgencmd measure_clock arm, it always shows only 1200MHz... while not in load it shows 600MHz. I can put force_turbo=1 (it stays on max)...

while overclock is in written state, it shows 1500, however it still runs only to 1200MHz. My Pi 02W runs faster :D Previous comment was with OC turned off.

So, it turned out it was power supply all the time. I was powering pi as normal person through Micro USB, with some phone charger. Now i am using same power supply, but with Power delivery trick board for taking 12V from adapter, and then buck converter with 5,15V and 4A current limit. I can now hit stable 1,5GHz like before. If only RPI foundation could give us proper powering option one day...

"If only RPI foundation could give us proper powering option one day... I was powering pi as normal person through Micro USB, with some phone charger." Actually phone chargers are not recommended for this purpose, they are for recharging devices that have batteries, not directly powering relatively high wattage 5V electronics, which require a supply capable of delivering fast instantaneous current (a charger does not have to do that, even if it otherwise meets the voltage and amperage requirements).  The "trick board" and buck converter provides this.

Funny, as i also happen to have Orange Pi zero 2 and zero 2w, and they can run from whatever, as they have proper power input circuitry (well Rpi zeros can run from almost whatever too...), believe me when i say it is not any random cheap phone charger too, but 20W branded one. Powering a single Pi3a+ should not be a problem, it would handle even two in my opinion. My mistake that i considered checking power input too late...

AFAICT the orange zeros have a USB-C connector, which if you have a 20W phone charger it certainly speaks USB-C (which is why you can draw 12V from it, otherwise it would be limited to 5V).  The 3a+ has a relatively dumb micro USB connection designed before USB-C was in widespread use, so does not communicate with the charger the way a USB-C device (or, presumably, your trick board) does.  I'm not disagreeing that Rpi's in general are a bit finicky WRT power, but that does not mean such problems cannot be explained and solved.
